# Match port number

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match port numbers in `<span>` tags from an html page:

```
<span class="tbBottomLine" style="width:50px;">
                8080
        </span>
<span class = "tbBottomLine" style = "width: 50px;">
            80
    </ span>
<span class = "tbBottomLine" style = "width: 50px;">
            3124
    </ span>
<span class = "tbBottomLine" style = "width: 50px;">
            1142
    </ span>
```

Script:

```
import urllib2
import re

h = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.proxy360.cn/Region/Brazil')

html = h.read()

parser_port = '<span.*>\s*([0-9]){2,}\s*</span>'

p = re.compile(parser_port)

list_port = p.findall(html)

print list_port
```

But I'm getting this output:

```
['8', '8', '0', '0', '0', '8', '8', '0', '0', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '8', '0']
```

And I need it to match `8080` for example.

Comment: And what is the end result you're looking for? Just the 8080?

Comment: I need a regex samples search all samples on

Comment: I'm sorry, you're still not making any sense. Am I correct to understand that after executing the regex, it would just find the 8080, 80, 3124 and 1142 as in your example? or does it also need to contain more?

Comment: yes, I just 8080, ...

Comment: @Michael Kjörling, Thanks

Comment: This is closer to what you are after [`>\s*([0-9]){2,}\s*<`](http://regexr.com/3c8at)

Comment: Ok, I did it, thanks

Comment: You have completely changed your question now. It is still not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Try `'<span[^>]*>\s*([0-9]{2,})\s*</span>'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: [*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”  Now they have two problems.* - Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are repeating the group `([0-9]){2,}`. which is overwritten with the last value.

Instead, repeat the subpattern *inside* the group:

```
<span[^>]*>\s*([0-9]{2,})\s*</\s*span>
```

**Code**

```
parser_port = '<span[^>]*>\s*([0-9]{2,})\s*</\s*span>'
p = re.compile(parser_port)

list_port = p.findall(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to pull the ports off the page.

```
parser_port = '<span.*>\s*([0-9]{2,})+\s*</span>'
```

You want one or more characters (the + sign) with a length of at least two (the {2,}. But still unclear as to what the use case is.